# Ruby parsing input file and put in hash

Tags: ruby, algorithm, file, hash, nodes

I got a file to represent adjacency list of nodes in a graph as a text file that I need to parse.  The first line is for the total number of nodes. Second line is node1, along with list of nodes it connects to (undirected graph).  For example

```
7
2 3 -1
1 3 4 5 7 -1
1 2 -1
2 6 -1
2 6 -1
4 5 -1
2 -1
```

line1: the graph has total 7 nodes.
line2: Node1 connects to Node2, Node3.
line3: Node2 connects to Node1, Node3, Node4, Node5, Node7.

The -1 is kind of useless.

Here is my current ruby implementation.  I am trying to find a way to set it up

```
def parse_file(filename)
  total_nodes = `wc -l "#{filename}"`.strip.split(' ')[0].to_i
  node_hash = Hash.new

  File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, line_num|
    # convert each line into an array
    line = line.strip.split(" ")
    # take out weird -1 at the end of txt file in each line
    line = line[0...-1]
    #puts "#{line_num}: #{line}"

    # how come node_hash[Node.new(line_num)] = line does not work?
    node_hash[Node.new(line_num)] = line
  end
end

parse_file('test_data.txt')
```

My node class has an adjacency_nodes array that I can push node2 and node3 into it.  For example: node1.adjancency_nodes  << node2

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :id, :state, :adjacent_nodes, :graph

  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
    @adjacent_nodes = []
  end

  def to_s
    "node #{@id}"
  end
end
```

What's the cleanest way to loop over the this text file, create new nodes and store it in a hash, along with pushing all of its adjacency nodes?

Comment: I am not at all goo with ruby, but I have done something similar so let me try something out.

Comment: If you can modify the contents of the file you might consider making a few changes. Firstly, I suggest you remove the node count on the first line, as that can be determined by counting lines. Secondly, begin each row with the node number. That makes the file more easily read by humans and avoids the need to have the rows ordered by row number. Thirdly, for each node only list the higher-numbered adjacent nodes. As the graph is undirected the reverse connections can be easily derived. That would be particularly helpful if hand-crafted files are used for testing.

Comment: I agree, the input file is so weird. It didn't occur to me to just edit it straight instead rather than using ruby to parse!

Comment: Developers come up with weird input formats all the time for their programs. The flexibility to reverse engineer and write a reader/writer is useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

That use of the system call is odd; you really don't need that to get the first line in a file.

First line represents number of nodes.

Each line after represents the adjacent nodes for the given node. line `n` represents the nodes for `node (n-1)`.

So you can just go line-by-line:

```
def parse_file(path)

  # start
  f = File.open(path, 'r')

  # get node count. Convert to integer
  num_nodes = f.readline.to_i

  # create your nodes
  nodes = {}
  1.upto(num_nodes) do |id|
    node = Node.new(id)
    nodes[id] = node
  end

  # join them and stuff
  1.upto(num_nodes) do |id|
    node = nodes[id]

    # for each line, read it, strip it, then split it
    tokens = f.readline.strip.split(" ")
    tokens.each do |other_id|
      other_id = other_id.to_i
      break if other_id == -1

      # grab the node object, using the ID as key
      other_node = nodes[other_id]
      node.adjacent_nodes << other_node
    end
  end

  # done
  f.close
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One might take advantage of ruby supporting technically infinite cross-nesting of objects:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :id, :adjacents
  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
    @adjacents = []
  end
  def to_s
    "<#Node #{@adjacents.map(&:id).inspect}>"
  end
end

class Graph
  attr_accessor :nodes
  def initialize(count)
    @nodes = (1..count).map(&Node.method(:new))
  end
  def to_s
    "<#Graph nodes: {#{@nodes.map(&:to_s)}}>"
  end
end

input = "7\n2 3 -1\n1 3 4 5 7 -1\n1 2 -1\n2 6 -1\n2 6 -1\n4 5 -1\n2 -1"

graph, *nodes = input.split($/)
count = graph.to_i

result =
  nodes.
    each.
    with_index.
    with_object(Graph.new(count)) do |(line, idx), graph|
      graph.nodes[idx].adjacents |=
        line.split.map(&:to_i).
          select { |e| e >= 1 && e <= count }.
          map { |e| graph.nodes[e - 1] }
    end
```

---

Now you have the infinitely nested graph (you might call `adjacents` on any node deeper and deeper getting the correct result.)

The top-level graph structure might be achieved with:

```
puts result.to_s
#⇒ <#Graph nodes: {["<#Node [2, 3]>",
#                   "<#Node [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]>",
#                   "<#Node [1, 2]>",
#                   "<#Node [2, 6]>",
#                   "<#Node [2, 6]>",
#                   "<#Node [4, 5]>",
#                   "<#Node [2]>"]}>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has all the hallmarks of a homework problem gone awry, but I'll try to help.

> My node class has an adjacency_nodes array that I can push node2 and node3 into it. For example: node1.adjancency_nodes << node2

Do you want to push the node ID onto the array, or the node reference itself?

> `# how come node_hash[Node.new(line_num)] = line does not work?`

What do you mean by it "does not work?" Does it not add the line to your hash?

You're building a hash where the keys are node references and the values are the adjacent nodes. You're not actually modifying the `adjacent_nodes` property of each node. Is that what you want to do? Also, if you have two lines that refer to the same node ID, e.g. `2`, you're going to instantiate that node twice, e.g. `Node.new(2)` will be called twice. Is that what you want to do?

Taking a look at what you've written, I notice a few things:

- You're using `String#strip` when you really just want to `String#chomp` the newline off the end of the string.
- You're ignoring valuable information at the top of the file, i.e. the total number of nodes.
- Worse, you're calling out to a shell command to get that information (just do it in Ruby!) instead, and you're doing it wrong: you're counting the line that contains the number of nodes as a node definition, so your `total_nodes` variable is being set to eight (not seven).
- You're ignoring valuable information at the end of each line. Yes, the `-1` terminator is kind of weird, but you can use it to determine when to stop processing the line. I reckon your professor plans to send in some bad input like `2 3 4 -1 5` to see if your code breaks. In this case, your code should only consider adjacent nodes 2, 3, and 4.
- You're not converting the strings containing numeric values to proper integers in all cases.
- What do you expect your `parse_file` method to return? It's probably not returning what you think it's returning as it's presently written.

With that in mind, let's make some changes:

- Let's read the first line of the input to determine the total number of nodes.
- Let's preallocate our nodes so we only instantiate each node once.
- Let's use an array (with zero-based indexes) to hold our node references. We'll have to keep this in mind when instantiating nodes and performing lookups against the array (with one-based node IDs).
- Let's stop processing adjacent nodes when we see an invalid node ID.
- Let's use `String#chomp` and `String#to_i` for all inputs.
- Let's actually append adjacent nodes...
- Let's return the nodes array at the end of the method so the caller gets back something helpful.

---

```
def parse_file(filename)
  # open the file in read-only mode
  file = File.new(filename, 'r')
  # read the first line as an integer to determine the number of nodes
  num_nodes = file.readline.chomp.to_i
  # preallocate our nodes so we can store adjacent node references
  nodes = Array.new(num_nodes) { |i| Node.new(i + 1) }

  # read the remaining lines containing node definitions
  file.each_line.with_index do |line, i|
    # parse the adjacent node ids as integers
    line.chomp.split(' ').map(&:to_i).each do |node_id|
      # a sentinel node id of -1 means stop processing
      break if node_id < 0

      # TODO: What's supposed to happen when the node doesn't exist?
      #raise "Unknown node ID: #{node_id}" if node_id == 0 || node_id > num_nodes

      # add the node reference to the list of adjacent nodes
      nodes[i].adjacent_nodes << nodes[node_id - 1]
    end
  end

  nodes
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  I don't think I need to worry about the cases.  Let's assume all input file will be correct.  So no 1 -1 4 7 or anything like that. The goal is just to create Nodes with list of other adjacent nodes. I will be using it for other section to build a graph. It's much easier to clean up the original file itself, but then it's more fun to try and leave it intact and see if i can work with it in ruby.